# Launching a GUI application in RHEL 5 hangs

Tags: linux, gnome, rhel, scim

When I try to launch any GUI application through a terminal in my RHEL 5.4, it takes a very long time for the GUI to come up.  Also, sometimes it just hangs.

I see the following messages in the terminal :

```
Launching a SCIM daemon with Socket FrontEnd...
GTK IM Module SCIM : Cannot connect to Panel!
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `env`? I'm especially interested in the content of `GTK_IM_MODULE`.

Comment: The GUI application may be hanging because of some other issue. The highlighted message is of "SCIM", which you can safely stop from being started at boot-time. Stop it for once and check the GUI apps.

Comment: Here is the o/p of env | grep "GTK*"
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/root/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
GTK_IM_MODULe=scim

Comment: Please make sure that GTK libraries are installed. try "export GTK_IM_MODULE=scim-bridge"

Answer (score 1):

Generally, issues like this can be fixed by updating and/or re-installing the GUI software. A configuration file may be corrupted or contain invalid syntax. Pin-pointing the problem with errors like this is difficult, so I cannot give a specific answer. If other RHEL 5 users are not having this problem on the same type of hardware, then the problem may lie in a configuration file or the graphics card. If many users with different hardware types have this problem, then it is a software bug that can be fixed with an update (when available).

Answer (score 1):

Check that your reverse DNS is configured correctly.  When it is not, strange things can happen. In particular, applications can take a long time to start (waiting for a reverse dns lookup timeout).

$ dig -x yourIP +short